Vite HMR working for single root file but not entire file tree
I wasn't sure where to ask this one, so I put it here, first. We're transitioning from a vanilla JS module/import application, with a single app.js being imported by our index.html page and the rest of the application being loaded via trees of imports strating from app.js. We're using Vite because of its drop-in TS support and it's been a breeze to use on other projects.
Knowns
Vite works like a charm. We're using the http://localhost:5173/assets/@vite/client import method to attempt to use Vite's HMR in an existing Flask application. The problem is that Vite's file watching and HMR system doesn't seem to be reloading the page or the required sections. Here's what I've established:

File-watching is working - Changing the vite.config.ts file does reload the whole page
This extends to files in the specified root — with the -d flag, I'm seeing changes reported in teh form of vite:hmr [file change] ... vite:hmr [no update happened].
If I replace the app.js from our existing application with a blank app.js and start changing console.log messages, everything works as expected.

Unknowns
This leads me to conclude that there must be something wrong with one or more files in the project hierarchy that is fooling with vite's HMR module.
Questions:

Does anyone know of valid JS conventions that might do this? Examples: circular imports, export const = "<blah blah>" or similar.
Does anyone have experience hacking Vite's HMR system in the type of project context I've defined here? I'd love to start debugging this myself.

